# Assign number to months within year within group

Tags: r

I want to assign numbers to month within group eg

[image]

How do I do this in R  ?

Comment: Could you clarify your example? it looks like you are counting months starting with January 2000. What has the "Group" to do with this numbering?

Comment: The count has to be done within each group not across group. That is from Jan 2000 to Dec 2003 within group. Thanks

Comment: Pictures are neither code nor data unless the question is about image processing. Please respect the time of contributors and follow the examples of other, _good_ questions and post code and data into proper code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the year and month to `yearmon` class.  Such objects internally represent the year/month as year + fraction where the fraction is 0 for Jan, 1/12 for Feb, 2/12 for Mar and so on. Now if we take the difference between the `yearmon` internal representation and 2000, multiply that by 12 and add 1 we will get the desired num.

```
library(zoo)

transform(DF, num = 12 * as.numeric(as.yearmon(paste(month, year), "%b %Y") - 2000) + 1)
```

giving:

```
  group month number year num
1     1   Jan      1 2000   1
2     1   Feb      2 2000   2
3     1   Apr      4 2000   4
4     1   Feb     38 2003  38
5     2   Aug      8 2000   8
6     2   Sep     21 2001  21
7     2   Apr     28 2002  28
```

**Note**: the input in reproducible form is as follows. We have included the `number` column so that we can compare it to the `num` column calculated above.

```
DF <- structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), month = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("Apr", "Aug", "Feb", "Jan", 
"Sep"), class = "factor"), number = c(1, 2, 4, 38, 8, 21, 28), 
    year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2003, 2000, 2001, 2002)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

Data:

```
group <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
month <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Apr", "Feb", "Aug", "Sep","Apr")
year <- c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2003, 2000, 2002)
number <- c(1, 2, 4, 38, 8, 21)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(group, month, number, year))
```

Create a function and apply:

```
mo2Num <- function(x) match(tolower(x), tolower(month.abb))
mo2Num(df$month)

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(val=mo2Num(month)) %>%
  data.frame()
```

Output:

```
  group month number year val
1     1   Jan      1 2000   1
2     1   Feb      2 2000   2
3     1   Apr      4 2000   4
4     1   Feb     38 2003   2
5     2   Aug      8 2000   8
6     2   Sep     21 2002   9
7     2   Apr      1 2000   4
```

Comment: the code didn't work very well. I don't know how to paste output every well. I could see that someone is already angry with the format of my table. I don't want to offend anyone. Please the values for val in your code :1,2,4,2,8,9 but what I want to generate is the "number" column in my data and in that order. Thanks

Comment: I have edited my post to show an output, is that what you are looking for? The code in the post assigns numbers to each month, i.e. `Jan = 1, Apr = 4, Sep = 9`.

Comment: Thanks for your responses and help. No. What I am looking for is to generate the values in the "number" column based on group, month and year column but the numbering should be within group across years 2000 - 2003.  Thanks

Comment: So what you want is to assign a number of `38` for `group = 1` , `month = Feb` and `year = 2003` and then assign a number of `21` for `group 2`, `month = sep` and `year = 2000`?

Answer (score 0):

I bet there are better ways of doing this but here it goes. Using package `zoo` function `as.yearmon`.

```
mon2num <- function(year, month){
  m <- zoo::as.yearmon(as.Date(paste(year, month, 1, sep = "-"), "%Y-%b-%d"))
  d <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), Sys.Date(), by = "month")
  d <- zoo::as.yearmon(d)
  match(m, d)
}

mon2num(df$year, df$month)
#[1]  1  2  4 38  8 21 28
```

To bind the return value to the original dataframe just

```
num <- mon2num(df$year, df$month)
cbind(df, Number = num)
#  group month number year Number
#1     1   Jan      1 2000      1
#2     1   Feb      2 2000      2
#3     1   Apr      4 2000      4
#4     1   Feb     38 2003     38
#5     2   Aug      8 2000      8
#6     2   Sep     21 2001     21
#7     2   Apr     28 2002     28
```

**Data.**
I will repost the data because in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249884/assign-number-to-months-within-year-within-group/53250174#53250174) by user113156 there are some values missing.

```
group <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
month <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Apr", "Feb", "Aug", "Sep","Apr")
year <- c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2003, 2000, 2001, 2002)
number <- c(1, 2, 4, 38, 8, 21, 28)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(group, month, number, year))
```

Comment: Thanks this works well. I just have to bind val to the data set. Thank you guys for all your responses.

Comment: @Jyde I have edited the answer. See if that is it.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can use `match` with some simple math

```
transform(df, number=match(as.character(month), month.abb) + (year - 2000) * 12)
#   group month year number
# 1     1   Jan 2000      1
# 2     1   Feb 2000      2
# 3     1   Apr 2000      4
# 4     1   Feb 2003     38
# 5     2   Aug 2000      8
# 6     2   Sep 2001     21
# 7     2   Apr 2002     28
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), month = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("Apr", "Aug", "Feb", "Jan", 
"Sep"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("group", "month"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```